# Use a storyboard to call a method in a usercontrol created dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, storyboard

to add clarity to the below.  I was considering using timers or storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated but the storyboard is for a metronome and the timings are in milliseconds: therefore:

CurrentTimeInvalidated does not raise events every millisecond from what I have seen in debug, it seems to raise every 200ms.

Timers have to be initialised in code and obviously this happens sequentially with the storyboard.begin.  as a result the timers go out of alignment over a period of about 30 seconds.

I think the title pretty much sums up what I want to do, but, in detail.

I have 8 user controls that are created dynamically at runtime.
I have a window that is running a storyboard and animation throughout the lifetime of the window (repeat behaviour = forever and autoreverse = true).

what I need to do is at set intervals in the storyboard call a method in the usercontrols (in sequence).

is it possible to bind to the storyboard and create a trigger that calls a usercontrol method?

thanks

Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the WPF frame rate is 60 FPS so millisecond UI updates are not possible. If you want to tap into the rendering of each frame, use `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx