# Invoke methods at specific times using a Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I would like to utilize a `Storyboard` object to invoke methods at specific times. Specifically; I am trying to make a fireworks display, with a `Firework` user control that has a `Fire` method. I want to create several of these controls and call their `Fire` methods at specific times (just like a real show).

Normally, you would use a `Storyboard` to animate properties of an object over time. **Is there a way to invoke a method instead?**

Something like (pseudo-code of course):

```
<Storyboard>
    <MethodUsingKeyFrames>
         <MethodKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" TargetName="Firework1" Method="Fire"/>
         <MethodKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" TargetName="Firework2" Method="Fire"/>
    </MethodUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I have considered just using a `Timer` on a high interval and doing the sequencing myself, but that seems like a hack; especially when we have such a nice existing way of doing it.

**Note:** Related to [Use a storyboard to call a method in a usercontrol created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180903/use-a-storyboard-to-call-a-method-in-a-usercontrol-created-dynamically) ; the question (at face value) seems to be the same, but the answer has nothing to do with what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: here is a simple idea: you need some `InvokeCommandAction` (in `System.Windows.Interactivity`, of course it's invoked when some trigger is fired. So you need to use the `Storyboard` to fire this trigger (such as by animating some property to the value which fires the trigger).

Comment: @KingKing I had thought of something like that; seems a bit hackish, but may be the best way to go. Certainly better than using a timer and handling the timing myself.

Comment: yes it's a bit hacky but currently XAML forces us to do fairly much hacky code (unless we use some custom library).

Comment: you should let this question open without any answer. So more users will notice about it and want to give their answers (I've personally rarely clicked on questions having at least 1 answer). Also I've not used InvokeCommandAction much, but it's fairly easy to use, you need a view model with some already command to bind... Even searching around could give you some sample using it.

Comment: @KingKing I'll do the googling of course :) Thanks for the help; and I'd be happy to see an answer formed for future users if nothing else. Perhaps you can answer after I already have another one :)

Comment: To future readers; I answered with my working solution. If you have another idea, I'd love to hear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up going with:

Add a dependency property `NeedsToFire` to the user control (a `bool`). Then handle the `PropertyChanged` event (via the metadata) with a function like:

```
public bool NeedsToFire
{
   get { return (bool)GetValue(NeedsToFireProperty); }
   set { SetValue(NeedsToFireProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NeedsToFireProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NeedsToFire", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(Firework), new PropertyMetadata(false, HandleNeedsToFire));

private static void HandleNeedsToFire(DependencyObject d, 
                                      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if ((bool)e.NewValue)
   {
      (d as Firework).Fire();
   }
}
```

Finally, use a `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to set this property at the correct time:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FireworksShow">
    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Firework1" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="NeedsToFire">
         <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"  Value="True" />
    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

This seems like the easiest to implement solution; even if it does require using Dependency Properties in a way they weren't necessarily intended to be. It also allows for repeat firing.