# wpf how to control storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a user control like this. (got it from code project and modified it)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataTransfer.View.CustomControls.CircularProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="120"

             Background="Transparent">
  <Grid>
    <Viewbox>
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="SpinnerScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="120" Height="120" >
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="20.1696" 
                            Canvas.Top="9.76358" 
                            Stretch="Fill" Fill="Orange" 
                            Opacity="1.0"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="2.86816" 
                            Canvas.Top="29.9581" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="5.03758e-006" 
                            Canvas.Top="57.9341" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.8"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="12.1203" 
                            Canvas.Top="83.3163" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="36.5459" 
                            Canvas.Top="98.138" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="64.6723" 
                            Canvas.Top="96.8411" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="87.6176" 
                            Canvas.Top="81.2783" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="98.165" 
                            Canvas.Top="54.414" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="92.9838" 
                            Canvas.Top="26.9938" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.2"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" 
                            Canvas.Left="47.2783" 
                            Canvas.Top="0.5" Stretch="Fill" 
                            Fill="Black" Opacity="0.1"/>
          <Canvas.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransform x:Name ="SpinnerRotate" Angle = "0" />
          </Canvas.RenderTransform>                    
            <Canvas.Triggers>
              <EventTrigger RoutedEvent ="ContentControl.Loaded" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard x:Name="CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                     Storyboard.TargetName ="SpinnerRotate" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                     From="0" To="360" 
                     Duration="0:0:01" 
                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                   </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
           </Canvas.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
      </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace DataTransfer.View.CustomControls
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for CircularProgressBar.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class CircularProgressBar : UserControl
  {
    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        Stop();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
      LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard.Begin();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
      LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

In my view

```
    <local:CircularProgressBar x:Name="cpb"  Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="563,0,117.667,278" RenderTransformOrigin="1.096,0.548" IsEnabled="{Binding CpbIsEnabled}" Visibility="{Binding CpbVisibility}"/>
```

I need to control stop and restart the animation. I can do it in the view code behind like this

```
private void BeginA(bool pBegin)
{
  if (pBegin == true)
  {
    cpb.CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard.Begin();
    cpb.LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  }
  else
  {
    cpb.CirccularProgressBarStoryBoard.Stop();
    cpb.LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  }
}
```

But I am looking to control it in the view model. How can I do it? 
I am thinking to control the start/stop by setting a bool property in the view model but not sure how to tie this property to the start/stop method.

Just trying to follow MVVM best practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a new question: **Ask a new question**. Edits are not for new questions; don't be a chameleon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ViewModel *shouldn't* be controlling a storyboard. The ViewModel knows *nothing* about the details of the view.

Now the ViewModel could set a property like `LoadingData`, that you would then trigger off of (using a `DataTrigger`) to start the storyboard. It could also raise an event `StartingLoad` that the view would register for.

Either way, the view chooses how to handle the state change or event that the View Model raises. The View Model does not start or stop the storyboard directly.

Comment: is there any way to bind a property from view model to the view on the control and use the property to reference the start/stop method?

Comment: @Shawn That is generally what a `DataTrigger` is used for, *especially* because you can start a storyboard directly from the XAML with one.

Comment: do you mean I should add a data trigger to the user control in parallel to the event trigger?

Comment: @Shawn Not necessarily; the data trigger needs two things: access to the storyboard, and access to the bound trigger. If those two things are never in the same place, you could consider using my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26684033/1783619

Comment: Bradley, I changed my code to use dependency property but the binding does not work. Can you point out what I did wrong?

Comment: @Shawn For starters, you put logic in the `set` of the DP. The `get/set` methods aren't actually ever used in a DP, you need to use the `PropertyChanged` event off the metadata instead. Get it down to the relevant code, and you could have a new question.